# JavaScript: Why does my program crash?

Tags: javascript

I need help checking over any errors for this assignment. My internet browser crashes when I run this script! I wrote this script entirely myself so it may be incorrect! This is an assignment for school in which we are to use loops to output the months of the year (in an array).

**PS: The program ran great until I created the break/continue code!**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Assignment 6: Steph Hussar</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Variable Declaration

        var monthArray = new Array ();
        monthArray[0]="January";
        monthArray[1]="February";
        monthArray[2]="March";
        monthArray[3]="April";
        monthArray[4]="May";
        monthArray[5]="June";
        monthArray[6]="July";
        monthArray[7]="August";
        monthArray[8]="September";
        monthArray[9]="October";
        monthArray[10]="November";
        monthArray[11]="December";


        // Using the for loop

        document.write("<h4>Using the for loop</h4>");

        for(var count =0 ; count < 12 ; count++)
        {
            document.write(monthArray[count] + "<br />");
        }

        // Using the while loop

        document.write("<h4>Using the while loop</h4>");

        var count = 0;
        while (count < 12)
        {
            document.write(monthArray[count] + "<br />");
            count++;
        }


        // Using for in loop

        document.write("<h4>Using for in Loop</h4>");

        for(index in monthArray)
        {
            document.write(monthArray[index] +"<br />");
        }



        // Using the Break

        document.write("<h4>Using the break when the month of March is found</h4>")

            for(count = 0 ; count < 12 ; count++)
            {
            if (count == 3)
                { 
                break;  
            }else{
             document.write(monthArray[count] + "<br />");

            }
            }
            document.write("I broke out of the loop!");

        // Using the Continue

        document.write("<h4>Using the continue when the month of March is found</h4>")      


            for(count = 0 ; count < 12 ; count++)
            {
            if (count == 2)
                { 
                continue;  
            }else{
             document.write(monthArray[count] + "<br />");

            }
            }
            document.write("I skipped March with a continue statement!");


    </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Ensure a semicolon is at the end of each javascript statement, especially the document.write statements.

Comment: Since it's homework, we won't tell you the answer. But as a tip, start commenting out individual loops until you find which one's causing the crash, then work on isolating which part of the loop causes it.

Comment: @JohnPick - actually semicolons aren't required in javascript.

Comment: I tested only the JS on Google Chrome (on Ubuntu) and I had no issue. Maybe the `</html>` is missing?

Comment: thanks, I added the missing semicolon! @marcB it's the break one that is creating the error

Comment: the </html> is in my code, just must of missed it copying it onto here! but thanks!

Comment: You still seem to be learning. The core you currently have is extremely bad and uses lots of deprecated practices (leaking globals, using `document.write`, improper use of `for(.. in ..)` loops); besides that the indentation of some parts of your code is really bad. While you might not be able/allowed to improve some of the things, I'd highly suggest you to throw this code away after turning in your assignment and learning JavaScript via a recent (2011+) book or guide - also consider jQuery as code using jQuery is usually not that old and often contains other good practices.

Comment: @StephanieKay - take a look at this, your break statement seems to be working (scroll past the errors) http://jsfiddle.net/eqrmh/

Comment: `"I skipped March with a continue statement”.”` Take a very close look at that string.

Comment: @thiefMaster I've just currently started javascript, this is my 5th week of class! i'm sorry it is horrible :( my teacher isn't helpful and she gives us certain standards we need to follow. I am writing the code to what she has given us, i cannot deviate from it. she is notorious for deducting points for straying from her written directions! :(

Comment: @StephanieKay: Don't sweat the criticisms. The `document.write` is useful for some basic output like you're doing. The `for-in` can be an issue, but if that's what teacher wants, that's what teacher gets. Don't even think about jQuery until you have the basics down.

Comment: i am a web design student, I won't be venturing much past xhtml, css, and flash for my career. unfortunately we have to take some programming for the degree since it is a web development and design degree, not just web design. that's why i'm so bad at this, this is my first programming course! "/

Comment: @amnotiam: `for-in` *is* and issue and if the teacher uses it to loop over arrays, maybe even with a global loop variable, he should be told that he's teaching something pretty bad.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: When I say it can be an issue, I mean that often times the code will work as expected irrespective of the fact that it's a wrong practice. Sounds to me like Stephanie just needs to get through the class.

Comment: ...and getting though classes can sometimes mean not letting the instructors know they're doing it wrong, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change this line:

```
document.write("I skipped March with a continue statement”.”);
```

To this:

```
document.write("I skipped March with a continue statement”.");
```

You aren't properly closing your quote.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me, but I'd try removing the curly quotes in your "I broke out of the loop”." strings. Depending on the browser, it may see the curly quotes as the end of the string, in which case the ." is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error here:

```
document.write("I skipped March with a continue statement”.”);
```

Note the weird end quote... The string is not properly quoted.

Answer (score 2):

You are really very close - just the If statements need to be fixed, I think - like this:

```
 // Using the Break          
   document.write("<h4>Using the break when the month of March is found</h4>")
  for(count = 0 ; count < 12 ; count++)             
  {             
     if (count == 2)  
     {    
       document.write("I broke out of the loop"); 
       break; 
      }
      else
     {              
       document.write(monthArray[count] + "<br />");
     } 
  }  
  // Using the Continue          
  document.write("<h4>Using the continue when the month of March is found</h4>")
  for(count = 0 ; count < 12 ; count++)             
  {             
  if (count == 2)  
  { 
    document.write("Skip March and continue<br />");   
    continue; 
   }
   else
   {    
    document.write(monthArray[count] + "<br />"); 
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it seems to be working fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/VvUW5/2/

I added in a few missing commas, fixed a broken string, and added some missing `var`'s.

Is it doing everything it is supposed to now, or is there another issue?